# How can I print escape characters in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

How can I print `\n`, `\t`, `\v` and so on in LaTeX document? I mean I want in my output two chars: `\n` not a new line.

I tried:

1. `\\n`
2. `\verb!\\n!`

With no effects...

Comment: `\textbackshlash n` works. This can be wrapped inside `\texttt{\textbackslash n}`. `\verb!\n!` should also work, but not in a parameter of a macro. (Also `\string\n` exists.) ``\\`` is already reserved for many “new line” purposes. If you often use these things, create a new macro: `\newcommand*{\escape}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}` which you can use then as `\escape{n}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Why don’t you post your comment as an answer?!

Comment: Agree, duplicate. I've flagged it as such.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `\verb"\n"` rather than `\verb!\n!`? The former works for me…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the first version.
Both the `I` and `II` version show other ways which are unnecessary complex (and exploit certain TeXnicalities).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newcommand*{\escape}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}
\newcommand*{\escapeI}[1]{\texttt{\expandafter\string\csname #1\endcsname}}
\newcommand*{\escapeII}[1]{\texttt{\char`\\#1}}
\begin{document}
    We escape \escape{n}, \escape{t} and \escape{v}.

    We escape \escapeI{n}, \escapeI{t} and \escapeI{v}.

    We escape \escapeII{n}, \escapeII{t} and \escapeII{v}.

    We escape \verb!\n!, \verb!\t! and \verb!\v!
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]